# Woocommerce set category minimum cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like block price for specific woocommerce category, now work only all category woocommerce my code. My category name is: stock . I want only use for this category.

I want that a user if buy stock category have to buy minimum 1200.

```
    // Set a minimum dollar amount per order
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_total' );
function spyr_set_min_total() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        // Set minimum cart total
        $minimum_cart_total = 1200;

        // Total we are going to be using for the Math
        // This is before taxes and shipping charges
        $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

        // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total
        // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
        // Will display a message along the lines of
        // A Minimum of 10 USD is required before checking out. (Cont. below)
        // Current cart total: 6 USD 
        if( $total <= $minimum_cart_total  ) {
            // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s %s is required before checking out.</strong>'
                .'<br />Current cart\'s total: %s %s',
                $minimum_cart_total,
                get_option( 'woocommerce_currency'),
                $total,
                get_option( 'woocommerce_currency') ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me the category ID of the `stock` ?

Comment: Yes, the category id is : 1441

Comment: Does it have any parent category ?

Comment: No, nothing. It's the main category.

Comment: Okay then try my answer ! I am posting ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code :

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_total' );
    function spyr_set_min_total() {
        // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
        if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

            global $woocommerce, $product;
            $i=0;
            //loop through all cart products
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :


                // Set minimum cart total
                $minimum_cart_total = 1200;

                // Total we are going to be using for the Math
                // This is before taxes and shipping charges
                $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

                // See if any product is from the STOCK category or not
                if ( has_term( '112', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :

                    //Get price of that product
                    $regular_price = get_post_meta($product['product_id'], '_sale_price', true); //change to _sale_price if it is in sale
                    //echo $regular_price."<br>";
                    $total = $regular_price * $product['quantity']; 
                    //echo $total."<br>";
                    $subtotal_cat += $total; //get total of 
                    //echo $subtotal_cat;
                    //$category_price += ( $product['line_subtotal'] + $product['line_subtotal_tax'] );

                endif;

            endforeach;
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :

                if ( has_term( '112', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :

                    // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total
                    // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
                    // Will display a message along the lines of
                    // A Minimum of 10 USD is required before checking out. (Cont. below)
                    // Current cart total: 6 USD 
                    if( $subtotal_cat <= $minimum_cart_total  ) {
                        // Display our error message
                        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s %s is required from stock category before checking out.</strong>'
                            .'<br />Current cart\'s total: %s %s',
                            $minimum_cart_total,
                            get_option( 'woocommerce_currency'),
                            $subtotal_cat,
                            get_option( 'woocommerce_currency') ),
                        'error' );
                    }
                endif;
            endforeach;

        }

    }
```

Let me know the output..

Comment: I test this code but not work, i have inserti in function.php.

Comment: Is it giving any error ?Try again above code ...  I have made changes to the code ..

Comment: Are you having regular price or sale price ? If it is sale price then you need to modify above code.

Comment: Yes i use sales price

Comment: Sorry the category tag_ID=112 i have change code and update category id but nothing. My first code work for all category .

Comment: Its working perfectly fine for me ..Can please update your question with what have you tried ?

Comment: Yes, i have add my code in function.php and my url.Thank you

Comment: Comment here whenever you come online .. We need to do little bit of debugging.I ll help you in that ..

Comment: Ok, tell me. I will send all info tha you will ask me. I follow your advice for debugging.

Comment: At what time will you available ? Coz we need to chat for that.

Comment: Today all day online 11 am - 24 pm

Comment: No, the checkout and cart is normal. But the price filter is not applicated

Comment: I guess I figured it out ... Try above code again ..I have edited that code ..
Let me know the output... Make sure you are adding the product from the category `112`.

Comment: Well don;t forget to upvote when stack overflow gives you that privilege at 15 reputation. Happy Coding !

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, i have insert it into function.php :
My category id : http://goo.gl/R197Bz

```
// start code
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_total' );
    function spyr_set_min_total() {
        // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
        if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

            global $woocommerce, $product;
            $i=0;
            //loop through all cart products
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :


                // Set minimum cart total
                $minimum_cart_total = 1200;

                // Total we are going to be using for the Math
                // This is before taxes and shipping charges
                $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;

                // See if any product is from the STOCK category or not
                if ( has_term( '112', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :

                    //Get price of that product
                    $regular_price = get_post_meta($product['product_id'], '_sale_price', true); //change to _sale_price if it is in sale
                    //echo $regular_price."<br>";
                    $total = $regular_price * $product['quantity']; 
                    //echo $total."<br>";
                    $subtotal_cat += $total; //get total of 
                    //echo $subtotal_cat;
                    //$category_price += ( $product['line_subtotal'] + $product['line_subtotal_tax'] );

                endif;

            endforeach;
            foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) :

                if ( has_term( '11', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) :

                    // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total
                    // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
                    // Will display a message along the lines of
                    // A Minimum of 10 USD is required before checking out. (Cont. below)
                    // Current cart total: 6 USD 
                    if( $subtotal_cat <= $minimum_cart_total  ) {
                        // Display our error message
                        wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s %s is required from stock category before checking out.</strong>'
                            .'<br />Current cart\'s total: %s %s',
                            $minimum_cart_total,
                            get_option( 'woocommerce_currency'),
                            $subtotal_cat,
                            get_option( 'woocommerce_currency') ),
                        'error' );
                    }
                endif;
            endforeach;

        }

    }
    // end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope this helps you

http://wordpress-code-snippets.blogspot.in/2017/02/woocommerce-set-minimum-quantity-for.html

```
     add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'restrict_product_quantity' );
      function restrict_product_quantity() {
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {  
        global $woocommerce;

        $pd_min_quantity= array( 
        array( 'id' => 3587, 'min' => 99),
        array( 'id' => 2554, 'min' => 87),
        array( 'id' => 5587, 'min' => 52),
        array( 'id' => 4488, 'min' => 40),
       array( 'id' => 2555, 'min' => 80),
);

        $i = 0;
        $odd_prod = array();

        foreach( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $pd_cart ) {
            foreach( $pd_min_quantity as $pd_quantity ) {
                if( $pd_quantity['id'] == $pd_cart['product_id'] ) {
                    if( $pd_cart['quantity'] < $pd_quantity['min'] ) {
                        $odd_prod[$i]['id'] = $pd_cart['product_id'];
                        $odd_prod[$i]['in_cart'] = $pd_cart['quantity'];
                        $odd_prod[$i]['min_req'] = $pd_quantity['min'];
                    }
                }
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if( is_array( $odd_prod) && count( $odd_prod ) > 1 ) {
            $message = '<strong>Minimum quantity per product should be added.</strong><br />';
            foreach( $odd_prod as $odd_prods ) {
                $message .= get_the_title( $odd_prods['id'] ) .' requires a minimum quantity of '
                         . $odd_prods['min_req'] 
                         .'. You currently have: '. $odd_prods['in_cart'] .'.<br />';
            }
            wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
        }
      }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the my code!

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'oxynergy_set_min_total' );
    function oxynergy_set_min_total() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {

        global $woocommerce, $product;
        $i=0;
        // Minimum order checking
        $minimumCheck = false;
        // Set minimum cart total
        $minimum_cart_total = 10;
        //loop through all cart products
        foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents as $product ) {
            // Total we are going to be using for the Math
            // This is before taxes and shipping charges
            $total = WC()->cart->total;

            // See if any product is from the STOCK category or not
            if ( has_term( 'STOCK', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) || has_term( '482', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] )  || has_term( '495', 'product_cat', $product['product_id'] ) ) {
                $minimumCheck = true;
                //Get price of that product
                $regular_price = get_post_meta($product['product_id'], '_regular_price', true); //change to _sale_price if it is in sale
                //echo $regular_price."<br>";
                $total = $regular_price * $product['quantity']; 
                //echo $total."<br>";
                $subtotal_cat += $total; //get total of 
                //echo $subtotal_cat;
                $category_price += ( $product['line_subtotal'] + $product['line_subtotal_tax'] );

            }


        }


            if ( $minimumCheck && $category_price <= $minimum_cart_total) {

                // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total
                // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
                // Will display a message along the lines of
                // A Minimum of 10 USD is required before checking out. (Cont. below)

                wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A Minimum of %s %s is required category before checking out.</strong>'
                        .'<br />Current cart\'s total: %s %s',
                        $minimum_cart_total,
                        get_option( 'woocommerce_currency'),
                        $category_price,
                        get_option( 'woocommerce_currency') ),
                    'error' );
            }


    }

}
```